# IP ping works but domain name doesn't

Tags: vmware, ip, domain

I am working on two VMs, the domains are ArcticIce.com and GlacierIce.com

They have static IPs `192.168.100.1` and `192.168.100.2`

DNS running on ArcticIce.com

I ran into this problem when trying to add a global group from GlacierIce.com to a universal group in ArcticIce.com. It is worth noting GlacierIce can ping ArcticIce, but not vice versa.

The host PC is running Windows 10, two VMs are Windows Server 2008. NICs from both VMs are set to NAT as default.

[image: arcticice dns server ipconfig /all]

Comment: I recommend you add tons of information, such as the exact DNS configuration of the two VMs, their host(s) (we can't guess whether it's the same), operating systems of the three / four involved physical and virtual machines, networking config of the VMs, and potentially even information regarding other DNS server(s) on your LAN...

Answer (score 0):

You say DNS is running on the system, however this is either not the case or it is not answering on 127.0.0.1 or there is a firewall in place blocking the requests (the last, I would imagine, is extremely unlikely).

I'd start by checking that the DNS server is actually running.